# Can I get fiber-like behavior from Rayon?

Tags: rust, rayon

Rayon works by creating a threadpool of workers, assigning each worker a workqueue, and allowing workers with an empty queue to steal work. But if a closure blocks (say, the work involves editing a shared resource under a Mutex), is the worker able to make progress on another work item, as with [cooperative multi-tasking fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))?

Context: I have a custom global priority queue of work which my rayon threads pop from and push to, but I'm not getting great parallelization for the actual cpu-bound work items, and I think maybe I should switch to [fibers](https://docs.rs/fibers/latest/fibers/) (the library) or [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/). My other option is to have more rayon threads in the threadpool than the "workers" that pop tasks, and have them create subtasks.

Comment: No, if the task blocks then the thread is blocked and will not be used. If your pattern is actually I/O bound and not CPU-bound, you should use `tokio` instead of `rayon`. If, however, it is blocked by accessing some shared resource, you probably cannot parallelize it efficiently, unless it needs to access the shared resource very rarely.

Comment: I would need `tokio`'s green tasks (fibers) more than the async I/O features.

Comment: I/O is what they're good at. What do you need them for?

Comment: I guess what I was looking for was a Mutex implementation that could collaboratively yield directly to a thread not waiting on a mutex, to make it simpler. What I've actually done in the end is reduce the number of highest-level tasks that do block, and split work better within them into non-blocking tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If some unit of work cannot currently make progress, then it could call [`rayon::yield_now()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/fn.yield_now.html) to allow other work to proceed. So, in principle, you could:

```rust
let guard = loop {
    match mutex.try_lock() {
        Ok(guard) => break guard,
        Err(TryLockError::WouldBlock) => rayon::yield_now(),
        Err(TryLockError::Poisoned(e)) => panic!("{e}"),
    }
};
```

However, this will waste some CPU time — more the longer the lock is held by other threads — since there is no way it can ‘wake up’ only when the lock is available. So, if you really have to do this, do it sparingly and measure the performance.

In general, Rayon is best at computational tasks which involve no blocking *except on other Rayon tasks,* with strictly tree-shaped dependencies.

If your tasks have more complex dependencies, consider using `async` instead, perhaps with a compute-focused async executor like [`switchyard`](https://docs.rs/switchyard/).

Comment: I'd recommend actually blockingly locking the mutex if `rayon::yield_now` returns `Some(Yield::Idle)` (which implies no other tasks were available). You could also use a timeout on the lock, to allow new `rayon` to be executed if they're created in the meantime.

Comment: This has a problem that the lock may never be acquire until the end, and then the task will be CPU-busy waiting for the lock.